# Como usar la function anónima de .done() para agregar parámetros adicionales?

Tags: jquery

/*el problemas es que pasa algo raro como si no se refrescaran las variables y me salen todas las tarjetas con las mismas imagenes y titulos pero si capta bien si una es pendiente y otra es visto, quiero pasar por parametro de la funcion an'onima de .done() o success: la verda da igual, solo para ver si se puede y de esa forma no tener que usar variables que al parecer estan dandome problemas*/

```
´´´var duration;
var file;
var title;
var respuesta;

$.ajax({
  url: "info/videos_carta.json",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data) {

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {   
      /*aqui agrego contenido a las variables*/
     duration = (data[i].HDURATION * 60 * 60) + (data[i].MDURATION * 60);   
     file=data[i].FILE;
     title=data[i].TITLE;
      
  $.ajax({
    url: "connect/get_video.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "video=" + data[i].TITLE + "&email=" + $("#user").text(),
    success: function (){
    }

  }).done(function(res){
        console.log(res);

     if(res > duration*0.5){

        /**Aqui pongo las variables del bucle ya que no puedo usar data[i].TITLE**/ 

     $("#cards_videos").append(`<div class='m-auto  d-inline-block p-3 video_div'><div style="background-image: url('Imagenes/videos/miniaturas/` + file + `');background-size: cover;border-radius:10px" class='shadow video_card'><div class='bg-deg' style='background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);border-radius:10px; z-index:1;width:100%; height:100%; text-align:right'><p class=' badge bg-success ms-auto m-2' style=' filter:none!important; position:relative '>Visto</p></div><a href='video.php?video=` + title + `' style='z-index:10000'><img src='Imagenes/video/play_icon.png' style='margin-top: -220.5px;z-index:10000;mix-blend-mode:normal'></a><strong><p class='text-white text-start p-2' style='font-family:Clemente;font-weight: bold;margin-top:-75px'>` + title + `</p></strong></div></div>`);
         
     }else{  
                    
            $("#cards_videos").append(`<div class='m-auto  d-inline-block p-3 video_div'><div style="background-image: url('Imagenes/videos/miniaturas/` + file + `');background-size: cover;border-radius:10px" class='shadow video_card'><div class='bg-deg' style='background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);border-radius:10px; z-index:1;width:100%; height:100%; text-align:right'><p class=' badge bg-warning ms-auto m-2' style=' filter:none!important; position:relative '>Pendiente</p></div><a href='video.php?video=` + title + `' style='z-index:10000'><img src='Imagenes/video/play_icon.png' style='margin-top: -220.5px;z-index:10000;mix-blend-mode:normal'></a><strong><p class='text-white text-start p-2' style='font-family:Clemente;font-weight: bold;margin-top:-75px'>` + title + `</p></strong></div></div>`);
    
     }

           imagen();    
  })
    }
    
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema es que `done` es un alias de `success` y se debe declarar como parte del objeto de la petición. No necesitas especificar los dos, solamente uno. Para mayor información lee [jQuery - Eventos AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).

Tampoco necesitas *"enviar parámetros"*, basta con que [declares las variables localmente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "info/videos_carta.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    // success debe ser parte del objeto de la petición
    success: function(data) {
        // Declara las variables para uso local, incluyendo la del ciclo
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let duration = (data[i].HDURATION * 60 * 60) + (data[i].MDURATION * 60);   
            let file = data[i].FILE;
            let title = data[i].TITLE;
            $.ajax({
                url: "connect/get_video.php",
                type: "POST",
                // Puedes usar un objeto para enviar los datos
                data: {
                    video: title,
                    email: $("#user").text()
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    // Aquí puedes usar las variables locales
                    // Incluso de data
                    if(res > duration * 0.5) {
                        console.log(title, file);
                    } else {
                        console.log(data[i].TITLE, data[i].FILE);
                    }
                } // Fin de success
            });
        } // Fin del ciclo for
    } // Fin de success, primera petición
});
```

Voy a tratar de explicar de forma sencilla la diferencia entre `var` y `let` para tu caso:

```
// Variable global
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // i es variable global y se va a actualizar en cada iteración
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: function(res) {
            // Las peticiones AJAX se ejecutan de forma asíncrona
            //     es decir, en un tiempo diferente al del ciclo
            // Seguramente el ciclo terminó de ejecutarse antes de esto
            //     la variable GLOBAL i SE ACTUALIZÓ
            //     siempre tendrá el valor de la última iteración
        }
    });
}

// Variable local
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // i es local, solo se mantiene dentro de cada iteración
    //     imagina que declaras una variable independiente cada vez
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: function(res) {
            // Las peticiones AJAX se ejecutan de forma asíncrona
            //     es decir, en un tiempo diferente al del ciclo
            // Seguramente el ciclo terminó de ejecutarse antes de esto
            //     la variable LOCAL i NO SE ACTUALIZÓ,
            //     conserva el valor asignado en cada iteración
        }
    });
}
```

Lo mismo pasa con las variables `duration`, `title` y `file`, si las declaras con `var`, se estarán actualizando en cada iteración del ciclo y no conservarán el valor deseado al momento de usarlas dentro de `success`; por eso debes declararlas con `let` dentro del bloque donde las quieras usar, en este caso, dentro del ciclo.